# Optimizing the FrameLabel size and PlotStyle

Tags: plotting

Here is the code I use to plot a graph

```
ant = Plot[{a3[t], n[t ], a1[t], a[t]}, {t, 0, 20},
 GridLines -> {{t0}, {1}}, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 800, 
  MaxRecursion -> 15, PlotStyle ->
   {{Orange, ck}, {Black, ck, Dashed}, {{Red, ck}, 
     DotDashed}, {Darker[Green], Dotted, ck}}, 
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 2}}, 
  PlotLegends -> 
   Placed[{"x = 0.05", "y = 0.03", " z = 0.7", "E = 0.1", 
     "F = -0.01" }, {0.3, 0.75}], FrameLabel -> {"t", "a"}, 
  LabelStyle -> 
   Directive[FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 25, Black], 
  GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Gray] ]
```

The png output is:

[image]

This graph has a couple of problems if you help me to fix. First how to increase the size of the `FrameLabel` `(a,t)` without increasing the size of the `PlotLegends` ?

In this code when I increase the `FontSize` in the `LabelStyle` it applies on both, so how to separate the `FontSize` of the `FrameLabel` and the `FontSize` of the `PlotLegends`?

Second: How to make the `PlotStyle` : (`Dashed` (Black), `DotDashed` (Red), `Dotted` (Green)) more distinct and apparent.

In short how to make my graph seems like for instance this graph:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use arbitrary function for an example:

```
a[t_] = 0.01 t^2;
a1[t_] = 1 + Cos[.5 t];
a3[t_] = Exp[-0.1 t];
n[t_] = Tan[0.4 t]
ant = Plot[{a3[t], n[t], a1[t], a[t]}, {t, 0, 20}, 
  GridLines -> {{t0}, {1}}, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 800, 
  MaxRecursion -> 15, 
  PlotStyle -> {{Orange, Thickness[0.008], ck}, {Black, ck, 
     Dashing[Large, Large], Thickness[0.008]}, {{Red, ck}, DotDashed, 
     Thickness[0.008]}, {Darker[Green], Thickness[0.008], Dotted, 
     ck}}, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 2}}, 
  PlotLegends -> 
   Placed[{"x = 0.05", "y = 0.03", " z = 0.7", "E = 0.1", 
     "F = -0.01"}, {0.3, 0.75}], 
  FrameLabel -> {Style["t", Bold, Larger], Style["a", Bold, Larger]}, 
  LabelStyle -> 
   Directive[FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 25, Black], 
  GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Gray]]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Hello, great thanks. But I wonder about the `PlotStyle` of  the red,  green, and black lines, how can they appear like the blue(DotDashed), the green (Dashed), and the cyan (Dotted) lines in the example graph I have  posted . There is a difference in thickness but still they look so clear in the example graph.

Comment: You can play e.g. with "Dashing" look it up in the help. The thickness is controlled by "Thickness".

Comment: Yeah, of course I know this. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

`AbsoluteDashing` is convenient to set the `PlotStyle`.

```
Plot[{Sqrt[x], Sqrt[2 x], Sqrt[3 x], Sqrt[4 x]}, {x, 0, 5}, 
 PlotStyle -> {{AbsoluteThickness[4], 
    Darker@Yellow}, {AbsoluteDashing[{10, 10}, 0, "Round"], 
    AbsoluteThickness[4], 
    Darker@Green}, {AbsoluteDashing[{1, 10}, 0, "Round"], 
    AbsoluteThickness[4], 
    Darker@Cyan}, {AbsoluteDashing[{10, 1, 10}, 0, "Round"], 
    AbsoluteThickness[4], Blue}}]
```

[image]

Comment: So awesome.. many thanks

Comment: I have Mathematica 12, have you an idea why it doesn’t recognize `0, "Round"]` option?

Comment: @Dr.phy   Maybe add `CapForm` in old version.  `Plot[{Sqrt[x], Sqrt[2 x], Sqrt[3 x], Sqrt[4 x]}, {x, 0, 5}, 
 PlotStyle -> {{AbsoluteThickness[4], 
    Darker@Yellow}, {AbsoluteDashing[{10, 10}, Automatic, 
     CapForm["Round"]], AbsoluteThickness[4], 
    Darker@Green}, {AbsoluteDashing[{1, 10}, Automatic, 
     CapForm["Round"]], AbsoluteThickness[4], 
    Darker@Cyan}, {AbsoluteDashing[{10, 1, 10}, Automatic, 
     CapForm["Round"]], AbsoluteThickness[4], Blue}}]`

Answer (score 2):

You can style frame labels, increasing the font size:

```
FrameLabel -> {Style["t", 40], Style["a", 40]}
```

Then there are various settings to play with to change the PlotStyle (Thickness, Dashing...). Here is an example.

```
PlotStyle -> {{Orange, ck, Thickness[0.01]}, {Black, ck, 
   Dashing[{0.05, Small}], 
   Thickness[0.01]}, {{Red, ck, Thickness[0.01]}, 
   DotDashed}, {Darker[Green], Thickness[0.01], Dashing[{0.1, Small}],
    ck}}
```